# I want to preview an excel file which is in base 64 format on click

Tags: reactjs

I have an excel file/spreadsheet which is in base 64 format. I want to get all the data of the spreadsheet including headers in JSON format and preview the excel file on click of a link. I have got the excel data but in base 64 format in props in the click of the link

Comment: you might want to check this out https://medium.com/hashmapinc/render-and-display-excel-sheets-on-webpage-using-react-js-af785a5db6a7

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work